# C++ compilation dependencies errors

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gcc, compiler-errors

I recently brew upgraded gcc [version 11.2.0_1] for some reason, and it deleted files from the previous version of gcc. This led to some problems in my editor - VS Code. I started getting includePath errors.

In order to fix them, I tried to edit the includePath in the configuration, and when that didn't work, I tried adding the header file VS Code couldn't open, manually, by getting the source online and putting it into a file in the directory in the includePath. However, there were too many files that VS Code couldn't open. So, I couldn't create them manually **one by one**.

So, I finally tried to change the compiler path in the configuration to "usr/bin/clang" and it worked. I stopped getting errors in VS Code.

Now, the main problem. After fixing the includePath issue, I cannot compile anything. Here's what the compiler says when I run `g++ hello-world.cpp`:

```
In file included from hello-world.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:85:
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:38:12: error: no member named 'abort' in namespace 'std'
using std::abort;
      ~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:39:12: error: no member named 'atexit' in namespace 'std'
using std::atexit;
      ~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:40:12: error: no member named 'exit' in namespace 'std'
using std::exit;
      ~~~~~^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:100:9: error: no member named 'div_t' in the global namespace
using ::div_t;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:101:9: error: no member named 'ldiv_t' in the global namespace
using ::ldiv_t;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:103:9: error: no member named 'lldiv_t' in the global namespace
using ::lldiv_t;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:105:9: error: no member named 'atof' in the global namespace
using ::atof;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:106:9: error: no member named 'atoi' in the global namespace
using ::atoi;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:107:9: error: no member named 'atol' in the global namespace
using ::atol;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:109:9: error: no member named 'atoll' in the global namespace
using ::atoll;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:111:9: error: no member named 'strtod' in the global namespace; did you mean 'strtok'?
using ::strtod;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:90:7: note: 'strtok' declared here
char    *strtok(char *__str, const char *__sep);
         ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:112:9: error: no member named 'strtof' in the global namespace; did you mean 'strtok'?
using ::strtof;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:90:7: note: 'strtok' declared here
char    *strtok(char *__str, const char *__sep);
         ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:113:9: error: no member named 'strtold' in the global namespace
using ::strtold;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:114:9: error: no member named 'strtol' in the global namespace; did you mean 'strtok'?
using ::strtol;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:90:7: note: 'strtok' declared here
char    *strtok(char *__str, const char *__sep);
         ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:116:9: error: no member named 'strtoll' in the global namespace; did you mean 'strcoll'?
using ::strtoll;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:78:6: note: 'strcoll' declared here
int      strcoll(const char *__s1, const char *__s2);
         ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:118:9: error: no member named 'strtoul' in the global namespace
using ::strtoul;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:120:9: error: no member named 'strtoull' in the global namespace; did you mean 'strcoll'?
using ::strtoull;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/string.h:78:6: note: 'strcoll' declared here
int      strcoll(const char *__s1, const char *__s2);
         ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:504:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:653:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:81:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:125:9: error: no member named 'rand' in the global namespace
using ::rand;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:126:9: error: no member named 'srand' in the global namespace
using ::srand;
      ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

I am really frustrated by this. Is there a way I could reinstall gcc, such that all dependencies come with it and this problem goes away?

Edit: here's my output for `gcc -v`

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: I think your problem is a conflict between your gcc version and the sdk you have installed  in macOS. Please wait for others I am not a macOS expert.

Comment: It makes sense, but I do not understand what exactly caused the problem in the first place. I only added some header files manually.

Comment: Have you updated your CLT or OS recently? Those are clearly not brew paths.

Comment: @sweenish yes. I updated to Monterey two weeks ago. However, it didn’t affect compilation. Everything got messed up only after I brew upgraded gcc

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `gcc --version`?  Also, as this is `C++` you should really be using `g++` rather than `gcc` .

Comment: What about the CLT? If you upgraded the OS, you must also upgrade the CLT. It appears that homebrew itself officially supports Moneterey, but I'm fuzzy on whether this means all the formulae have also been updated. If it's still broken after updating the CLT, you might just out of luck until the formulae you need update with Moneterey support.

Comment: @sweenish Is it just that `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/` is missing some headers, and if I replace the directory with one from another Mac [with the same OS] that hasn't had this issue yet, would it solve it?

Comment: From the output of `gcc --version` you appear to be using the default tool chain which is `clang` based.  Where did `brew` install `gcc`?  Do you have a file or symlink at `/usr/local/bin/gcc-11`?  Again, though, you should be invoking the compiler as `g++` as that *should* fix up the system include paths correctly.

Comment: @G.M. 
`brew` installed gcc here: `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1`. And using `g++` gives me the same error.

> Do you have a file or symlink at /usr/local/bin/gcc-11?
I do not.